# T extends abstract class constructor

Tags: typescript

Can I make this code work(interface is not a solution - this is a simplified example)? I am not going to create an abstract class.

> TS2511: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

```
abstract class AbstractBase {
  private readonly ["AbstractBase"];
}


class A extends AbstractBase {}
class B extends AbstractBase {}
class C extends AbstractBase {}


function create<T extends typeof AbstractBase>(c: T) {return new c();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes by definition do not have a callable constructor, so `typeof AbstractClass` will not have a callable constructor either. You can use a constructor instead

```
abstract class AbstractBase {
  private readonly ["AbstractBase"];
}


class A extends AbstractBase {}
class B extends AbstractBase {}
class C extends AbstractBase {}


function create<T extends new () => AbstractBase>(c: T) {return new c();}
```

Comment: I use a similar solution, but this is a hack. I want a beautiful solution without writing additional code.



`interface Constructor<T> {
  new(...arg: any[]): T;
  prototype: T;
}`

`type hack<T> = T extends Constructor<any> ? T : Constructor<any> & T;`

`function create<T extends hack<typeof AbstractBase>>(c: T) { return new c(); }`

Comment: @tarnose not sure why you say it's a hack. `typeof AbstractClass` is the class itself with all that represents including abstractness . The constructor signature represents a constructor that returns a new instance of a specific type. For non abstract classes these overlap somewhat, for abstract classes they do not.. It's just the way the type system works.. It's not a hack